# google calendar api v3 help in generating link

Tags: excel, vba, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to make the quick add event work so that I can run the quick add in microsoft excel vba, so I can get events directly added from excel. I found that I could possibly use the link:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[CALID]/events/quickAdd?key=[API KEY]&text=[QUICK ADD TEXT]&sendNotifications=true

```
CALID = Id of calandar
API KEY = Api key
QUICK ADD TEXT = text for quick add in google cal
```

but it doesnt seem to work? Does this have something to do with 0auth or is this just something that is impossible?

I seem to get the error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

Many thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Why is this tagged google-maps-api-3?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the API itself, not the OAuth authorization. It could be a permission problem.

1. For this to work check if you have shared the calendar with the service account.This is just like sharing your calendar with another person, but using your service account email address.
2. Also check if the authorization scopes match your sharing permissions (maybe try read-only).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have managed to get a little further I think, All I am wanting to do is be able to pop in that link to a browser and then have the event added to the calendar. I have changed the calendar to be public and shared the calendar with the service account and I still get the same problem! I seem to have jumped into the deep end!